# Fichero a Array de Integer

Tags: c#, linq

Actualmente tengo un fichero txt donde existen multitud de lineas, cada una de estas lineas puede ser un string, un entero, un salto de linea, etc...
El caso es que estoy buscando una manera limpia de cargar en una lista de enteros aquellas lineas que sean enteros.

Haciendolo mediante bucles y comparaciones no es problema pero quisiera hacerlo usando Linq.

Actualmente estoy en este punto:

```
List<int> lista = new List<int>();
lista = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split(' ').;
```

No consigo encontrar la manera de filtrar a partir del Split

Tampoco me importaría que que el resultado se guardase en un array de enteros.

Edit:
Haciendolo "a lo bruto", con bucles y demas me funciona, quedaria asi:

```
            List<int> lista = new List<int>();

            List<string> temp = new List<string>();
            temp = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split(' ').ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i< temp.Count; i++)
            {
                if (temp[i].Length > 0)
                {
                    int x = int.MinValue;
                    try
                    {
                        x = int.Parse(temp[i]);
                        if (x > int.MinValue)
                            lista.Add(x);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    { }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Por lo que entendi tu separador es un cambio de línea no un espacio en blanco

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar el código imperativo (bucles y comparaciones como los llamas) que si funciona para poder convertirlo a LINQ?

Comment: ¿Y por cierto, porque inicializas lista con un `new List<int>()` si luego lo vas a chancar en la línea siguiente?

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Ya lo he editado, como ves no queda muy elegante, funciona, pero tengo la sensacion de que eso se podria hacer en una linea con Linq, solo que no lo consigo. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias maneras de hacer lo que quieres, yo te muestro una a continuación.

Lo que debes hacer es seleccionar primero las lineas que puedan ser parseadas a `int` con un `Where` utilizando `int.TryParse`.Posteriormente se hace un `Select` de estas líneas usando `int.Parse`.Finalmente, se usa `ToList<int>`. Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
int entero;
string[] prueba = new string[] { "1", "a", "b", "5" };
var lista1 = prueba.Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out entero))
                   .Select(x=>int.Parse(x))
                   .ToList<int>();
```

En tu caso, te debe quedar lo siguiente:

```
int entero;
var lista=streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split(' ')
                       .Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out entero))
                       .Select(x=>int.Parse(x))
                       .ToList<int>();
```

Comment: Perfecto! muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

La respuesta de Pikoh está bien sin embargo no hay necesidad de hacer dos veces el `Parse` o `TryParse`:

Sintaxis de query

```
int entero = 0;
var lista = from x in streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split(' ')
            where Int32.TryParse(x, out entero)
            select entero;
```

Sintaxis de métodos

```
int entero = 0;
var lista = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split(' ')
    .Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out entero))
    .Select(x => entero);
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta tambien. La verdad es que acostumbrado a la sintaxis de lambdas no suelo usar la de queries. En cuanto a usar `entero`, tienes razón, pero pensé que quizá quedaría mas claro con el `parse` posterior :)